# How to scrape all image links from elements with specific class?

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to ask how can I get all image links from elements with same `class`. The website code I want to get is similar to this.

```
<div class="a">
<img  src="abc.com/breadcrumb-1-3000x300.jpg" data-src="abc.com/image-1.jpg" >
</div>
<div class="a">
    <img  src="abc.com/breadcrumb-2-3000x300.jpg" data-src="abc.com/image-2.jpg" >
</div>
<div class="a">
    <img  src="abc.com/breadcrumb-n-3000x300.jpg" data-src="abc.com/image-n.jpg" >
</div>
<div class="bcd">
    <img  src="abc.com/xyz.jpg" data-src="abc.com/image-xyz.jpg" >
</div>
```

If I use this code, it will get all the image links, including those that are in another `class`, not the one I want to get.

```
images = []
for img in soup.findAll('img'):
    images.append(img.get('src'))

print(images)
```

How can I get only image links of `class` a?

Answer (score 0):

Select more specific and include parent element with its class for example with [`css selector`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#css-selectors):

```
[e.get('src') for e in soup.select('div.a img')]
```

*In newer code avoid old syntax `findAll()` instead use `find_all()` or `select()` with `css selectors` - For more take a minute to [check docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#method-names)*

###### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = '''
<div class="a">
<img  src="abc.com/breadcrumb-1-3000x300.jpg" data-src="abc.com/image-1.jpg" >
</div>
<div class="a">
    <img  src="abc.com/breadcrumb-2-3000x300.jpg" data-src="abc.com/image-2.jpg" >
</div>
<div class="a">
    <img  src="abc.com/breadcrumb-n-3000x300.jpg" data-src="abc.com/image-n.jpg" >
</div>
<div class="bcd">
    <img  src="abc.com/xyz.jpg" data-src="abc.com/image-xyz.jpg" >
</div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

[e.get('src') for e in soup.select('div.a img')]
```

###### Output

```
['abc.com/breadcrumb-1-3000x300.jpg',
 'abc.com/breadcrumb-2-3000x300.jpg',
 'abc.com/breadcrumb-n-3000x300.jpg']
```